# sqlite - How does the command tool command .dump affect connected applications?

Tags: sqlite, backup, restore, database-backups, database-restore

I'd like to know how the .dump command affects other applications connected to the same database. I'd like to know this for the following journal modes:

> - DELETE  (the default mode)
> - WAL  (write-ahead-logging)

From reading other posts on this forum .backup uses the online backup API of SQLite. It would be great to have this confirmed as well.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.dump` command reads the contents of the database normally, just as if you would do a bunch of SELECT queries inside a transaction.
This means that when not using WAL, other connections cannot write as long as the dump is running.